# Find multiple characters in string AFTER substring

Tags: c, string, strstr

So I have this problem, where I have a string like this with points:

`"TaskA:55 TaskB:23....."` etc.
Is there a function with witch I can get the points from this?
I'm familiar with `strstr`, but that returns me the pointer to the first letter of the word if found if I'm correct, so how do I get the number after?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Can't you use [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)?

Comment: A string with "points"? Do "points" mean a colon (:)?

Comment: Points refer to the result, like 55, or 23.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on **:** and then take the second part. The second part is the numerical value which you require.

Comment: This is more a comment than a proper answer. Please provide an example

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I’ll update it

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr), and try to find the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the string. strtok() will modify the string passed into it so if the original string is required elsewhere, make a copy of it and pass the copy to strtok().